# No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined with Spring javaconfig

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-java-config

I am in reference to [the following spring documentation section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) as I am trying to instanciate an entityManagerFactory bean using javaconfig.

My app starts ok but when I open a page, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:114)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:229)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

I am not sure what I am getting wrong with my Data/JPA configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class DataConfiguration {

    @Value("${database.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${database.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${database.validationQuery}")
    private String validationQuery;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1800000);
        dataSource.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1800000);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(5);
        dataSource.setLogAbandoned(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandoned(Boolean.TRUE);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePersistence persistenceProvider() {
        return new HibernatePersistence();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.bignibou.domain");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(persistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(propertiesMap());
        //entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    public Map<String, String> propertiesMap() {
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        propertiesMap.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
        return propertiesMap;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit**: Taking into account Marten's comment I altered my webApplicationInitializer as follows:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(BaseConfiguration.class);
        rootContext.setConfigLocations(new String[] { "classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml" });

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());

        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr;

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter", new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        fr = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        fr.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        mvcContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("bignibou", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");


    }
}
```

I would have thought that I could have:

- a rootContext with both one @Configuration class and xml files **AND**
- an mvcContext with a @Configuration class

Unfortunately it does not work as expected: I still get BeanCreationException and NoSuchBeanDefinitionException...

Anyone any clue?

**edit 2**: I moved to all javaconfig using just one @ImportResources in order to import the one xml config file.

Comment: Where is the `EntityManagerFactory` injected?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It must be used by the oem filter I presume...

Comment: see here:  **org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:114)    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:229)**

Comment: Let's see how you register this `@Configuration` class.

Comment: SotiriosDelimanolis: if I understand what you said previously, only the @Configuration classes annotated with Component scan need to be declared in the WebApplicationInitializer. Am I right? Also, the app deploy ok. It is only when accessed from a browser that the OEM filter complains...

Comment: Not quite. The `@Configuration` (which is also a `@Component` type) class needs to be registered explicitly in an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` or it needs to be scanned for by another classes `@ComponentScan` or `<component-scan>`. If your `DataConfiguration` isn't registered in any of those, then its beans won't be added.

Comment: It seems it is already scanned by my BaseConfiguration class (itself registred in the webappinitiliazer: @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bignibou", 
excludeFilters = {  @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = RooRegexFilter.class),
     @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class) })

Comment: No that won't do it. Instead, add an `@Import` annotation to your `BaseConfiguration` class for the `DataConfiguration` class. This way it will be bootstrapped. It turns out that simply component-scanning doesn't bootstrap it only generates a bean, my mistake.

Comment: Ummm. Are you positive about the import being necessary? Because it really seems that the data config class was picked up by Spring... The issue really is with the oem filter not being able to find my entitymanagerfactory...

Comment: The filter searches your context for a bean of type `EntityManagerFactor`. If it can't find it, it means it's not in the context.

Comment: The `OEMIVF` scans the ROOT context (loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`) for a bean of type `EntityManagerFactor`. My guess is you are loading this configuration in the `DispatcherServlet` instead, that way it isn't visible to the filter.

Comment: @Marten. You're right. That must be the issue. I've tried as advised and edited my post accordingly.